Openssh server on add feature on system32 won't uninstall successfully
been having this issue ever since:
The OpenSSH SSH Server service could not be started.

A system error has occurred.

System error 1067 has occurred.

The process terminated unexpectedly.

Openssh server on add feature on system32 won't uninstall successfully.
I get error on safe mode delete force
Could be due to latest patch
.NET Framework 4.8
 Administrator Command Prompt
microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.20348.2762]
Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
c:\Users\bob>rmdir /s /q C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH 
c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\LICENSE.txt - Access is denied. 
c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\NOTICE.txt - Access is denied.
c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\scp.exe - Access is denied.
c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\sftp.exe - Access is denied. 
c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-add.exe - Access is denied. 
c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-agent.exe - Access is denied. 
c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-keygen.exe - Access is denied. 
c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-keyscan.exe - Access is denied.
c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-pkcsll-helper.exe - Access is denied. 
c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh-sk-helper.exe - Access is denied. 
c:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe - Access is denied.


In Windows, you may need to take ownership of the folder, then reset the permissions.

I resolve this with reinstall and fix programdata/ssh permission as well as logs folder.
this reinstall was using new 9.8.1.0p1 patch 64.  also thought I needed to add more permission did a "net user root" on ssh but I remove to fix it.
Permission got changed based on new patch.
Security Update for Microsoft Windows (KB5044281) 10/12/2024
Update for Microsoft Windows (KB5044025) 10/12/2024
was able to fix by rerunning ./fixhostfilepermiision PS1 file
